# Is the runtime complexity of symmetric difference using two different definitions supposed to be equivalent?

Tags: performance, function, runtime, big-o, time-complexity

Symmetric difference have two definitions which are equivalent mathematically, I have 3 functions that can make up symmetric difference but when I try to find the total complexity with the two definitions I get two different expressions.

These are the runtimes of the functions:

```
int minus(int a[], int b[])    //O(alogb)//here a and b denotes the size of the arrays
int union(int a[], int b[])    //O(a+b)
int intersect(int a[], int b[])//O(alogb)//a is the smaller array WLOG
```

Using the first definition for symmetric difference (a union b)-(a intersect b):

Pseudo code:

```
int xor(int a[], int b[]){
    u = union(a,b);
    i = intersect(a,b);
    minus(u,i);
}
```

So the runtime complexity would be: `O(a+b+alogb+(a+b)log(alogb))`

Using the other definition (a-b)union(b-a):

```
int xor(int a[], int b[]){
    m1 = minus(a,b);
    m2 = minus(b,a);
    union(m1,m2);
}
```

So the runtime this time would be `O(alogb+bloga+alogb+bloga)=O(2(alogb+bloga))`

They are quite different as you can see although I tried to place numbers in both expressions and the results are very close.

My question is, shouldn't both complexities be identical since they're supposed to be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just because two algorithms are equivalent (produce the  same result over the domains in which they are defined) does not mean that they will have the same run-time complexity.   For example, I can compute the multiple of two integers by using the usual base-B multiplication algorithm (O(n^2)), or I could use the Karatsuba algorithm, with complexity (O(n^k);k approx. 1.59)...  both yield the same result and therefore equivalent, but one is faster in asymptote.

That said, you are not understanding big-O notation.   It is really a limit in which lower order terms disappear so to abuse notation O(2a^2) = O(a^2) = O(a^2+a), etc.  For both of your above methods just write O(n*log(n)) - they are the same asymptotic complexity.